# Swap zeros in numpy matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, scikit-learn

I have a numpy matrix like so:

```
array([[2,  1, 23, 32],
       [34, 3, 3, 0],
       [3, 33, 0, 0],
       [32, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Now I want to shift all the numbers to the right and swap the zeros to the left like so:

```
array([[2, 1,  23, 32],
       [0, 34, 3,  3],
       [0, 0,  3,  33],
       [0, 0,  0,  32]], dtype=int32)
```

Is there as a short pythonic way of doing this, perhaps with api method from numpy, pandas or scikit-learn?

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: Yes! I'm trying to decide what answer to accept, it's hard

Answer (score 3):

Here's a vectorized approach with [`masking`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) -

```
valid_mask = a!=0
flipped_mask = valid_mask.sum(1,keepdims=1) > np.arange(a.shape[1]-1,-1,-1)
a[flipped_mask] = a[valid_mask]
a[~flipped_mask] = 0
```

Sample run -

```
In [90]: a
Out[90]: 
array([[ 2,  1, 23, 32],
       [34,  0,  3,  0],  # <== Added a zero in between for variety
       [ 3, 33,  0,  0],
       [32,  0,  0,  0]])

# After code run -

In [92]: a
Out[92]: 
array([[ 2,  1, 23, 32],
       [ 0,  0, 34,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  3, 33],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 32]])
```

One more generic sample run -

```
In [94]: a
Out[94]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2]])

# After code run -

In [96]: a
Out[96]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2]])
```

**Runtime test**

Approaches that work on generic cases -

```
# Proposed in this post
def masking_based(a):
    valid_mask = a!=0
    flipped_mask = valid_mask.sum(1,keepdims=1) > np.arange(a.shape[1]-1,-1,-1)
    a[flipped_mask] = a[valid_mask]
    a[~flipped_mask] = 0
    return a

# @Psidom's soln            
def sort_based(a):
    return a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:, None], (a != 0).argsort(1, kind="mergesort")]
```

Timings -

```
In [205]: a = np.random.randint(0,4,(1000,1000))

In [206]: %timeit sort_based(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 30.8 ms per loop

In [207]: %timeit masking_based(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.46 ms per loop

In [208]: a = np.random.randint(0,4,(5000,5000))

In [209]: %timeit sort_based(a)
1 loops, best of 3: 961 ms per loop

In [210]: %timeit masking_based(a)
1 loops, best of 3: 151 ms per loop
```

Comment: What about timings? Can you compare solutions? Thanks.

Comment: @jezrael Added for the solutions that try to solve for generic cases.

Answer (score 2):

pandas method:

```
In [181]:
# construct df from array
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
# call apply and call np.roll rowise and roll by the number of zeroes
df.apply(lambda x: np.roll(x, (x == 0).sum()), axis=1).values

Out[181]:
array([[ 2,  1, 23, 32],
       [ 0, 34,  3,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  3, 33],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 32]])
```

This uses `apply` so we can call `np.roll` on each row by the number of zeroes in each row

Comment: Doesn't `df.apply` just iterate through the rows?  How about applying the same `lambda` to each row of the array, without the `pd` conversion?

Comment: @hpaulj yeah it does, `np.roll` doesn't accept anything other than a scalar which is why I did it this way

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `numpy.argsort` with [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
arr[np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:, None], (arr != 0).argsort(1, kind="mergesort")]

#array([[ 2,  1, 23, 32],
#       [ 0, 34,  3,  3],
#       [ 0,  0,  3, 33],
#       [ 0,  0,  0, 32]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: That won't keep the order. You need to use `'mergesort'` to do so. Good idea by the way and short one as asked in the question!

Comment: @Divakar You're right. Didn't pay attention to that.

Answer (score 0):

Trivial attempt in non-numpy based python -

```
>>> arr = [[2,  1, 23, 32],
...        [34, 3, 3, 0],
...        [3, 33, 0, 0],
...        [32, 0, 0, 0]]
... 
>>> t_arr = [[0 for _ in range(cur_list.count(0))]\
            + [i for i in cur_list if i!=0]\
            for cur_list in arr]
>>> t_arr
[[2, 1, 23, 32], [0, 34, 3, 3], [0, 0, 3, 33], [0, 0, 0, 32]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also perform sorting on the masked array with the help of [`numpy.ma.sort()`](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:QVLm2tdLlw8J:https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.sort.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in&client=firefox-b-ab) that sorts the array in-place along the last axis, `axis=-1` as shown:

```
np.ma.array(a, mask=a!=0).sort()
```

Now `a` becomes:

```
array([[ 2,  1, 23, 32],
       [ 0, 34,  3,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  3, 33],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 32]])
```

The only downside is that it is not as fast as some of the approaches mentioned above but nevertheless a short one-liner to have.

Answer (score 0):

A row roll based solution, in the spirit of `@EDChum's` pandas version:

```
def rowroll(arr):
    for row in arr:
        row[:] = np.roll(row,-np.count_nonzero(row))
    return arr
In [221]: rowroll(arr.copy())
Out[221]: 
array([[ 2,  1, 23, 32],
       [ 0, 34,  3,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  3, 33],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 32]])
```

`np.count_nonzero` is a fast compiled way of finding the number of nonzeros.  It is used by `np.where` to find its return size.

But looking at the `np.roll` code, I think it's overly complicated for the task, since it can work with several axes.

This looks messier, but I suspect it's as fast, if not faster than `roll`:

```
def rowroll(arr):
    for row in arr:
        n = np.count_nonzero(row)
        temp = np.zeros_like(row)
        temp[-n:] = row[:n]
        row[:] = temp
    return arr
```

The `roll` solutions require trailing 0s in the original, not scattered 0s.